# why my code returns TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable?

Tags: python-3.x, string, dictionary, nonetype

i am trying to define a function which checks strings whether they contains the word from a dictionary and return true along with which word matched . Below is the snippet of code , everything works fine when a word matches in the string from dictionary.

```
def trigcheck(strings,a):
    try:
        str = strings.split()
        m=''
        a_match = [True for match in a if match in str]
        a=[m for m in a if m in str]
        if True in a_match:
            return True,a[0]

    except:
        return False,""

bool1,w=trigcheck("kjfdsnfbdskjhfbskdabs",['hello','do'])
print(bool1)
print(w)
```

I was expecting that with  string that doesn't match should return False and ' ' . But it throws error saying:

```
bool1,w=trigcheck("kjfd s n f dobdskjhfbskdabs",['hello','do'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: if no exception and no match, your function returns None

Comment: probably also you should not use `str` as a variable name since that is a built in.

Comment: if that's the problem then it shouldn't even return true on successful match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't raise an exception, and `True` is not in `a_match`, you don't explicitly `return` at all, causing you to return `None` implicitly. Unpacking `None` to `bool1` and `w` is what raises the exception.

Fix your code by making the exceptional return unconditional if the `if` check fails:

```
def trigcheck(strings,a):
    try:
        str = strings.split()
        m=''
        a_match = [True for match in a if match in str]
        a=[m for m in a if m in str]
        if True in a_match:
            return True,a[0]

    except Exception:  # Don't use bare except unless you like ignoring Ctrl-C and the like
        pass
    # Failure return is outside except block, so fallthrough reaches
    # it whether due to an exception or because the if check failed
    return False,""
```

Additional side-note: Your test for a `match` existing is relatively inefficient; it can't short-circuit, and requires a temporary `list`. Replacing the body of your function with the following code which relies on your exception handling to return when there are no matches:

```
def trigcheck(strings,a):
    try:
        strings = strings.split()  # Don't nameshadow builtins, reuse strings instead of shadowing str
        return True, next(m for m in a if m in strings)
    except StopIteration:
        return False, ""
```

reduces three scans and a two temporary `list`s to a single scan and no temporary lists, and avoids silencing random exceptions (e.g. a `TypeError` because someone passed a non-string or non-iterable as an argument) by only catching the one that indicates a failure to find a match.

Comment: A possible fix then might be do `pass` in except and return `False, ""` at the end?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh: Yeah, I was writing that up when you commented. :-)